# DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate binding at code behind

Tags: c#

I want to bind the column values DataGridTemplateColumn but I am not able to bind the things
.. here is my code

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <TextBox Text="{Binding x, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat={}\{0:N2\}%}">

                                                                <TextBox.Style>
                                                                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                                                        <Setter Property="Background">
                                                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource v2b}" ConverterParameter="column header">
                                                                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"/>
                                                                                    <Binding Path="."/>
                                                                                </MultiBinding>
                                                                            </Setter.Value>
                                                                        </Setter>
                                                                    </Style>
                                                                </TextBox.Style>
                                                            </TextBox>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Comment: Please format your code in an readable way.

Comment: I want to bind cell template property at code behind.. I had tried to format it but it's not.thanks in advance

Comment: I am talking about indents here in the forum post.